# Display Name Value instead of ID in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I currently utilize the below MVC tags to load a list of Vendor Names to a drop down list. I would like to add an input field that displays the name of the vendor saved into the database.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.InvoiceMaster.VendorId, new SelectList(Model.VendorId, "Id", "Name"), "Select Status", new { @class = "form-control col-lg" })
```

When I implement the below tag I can only get it to display the VendorID but not the name.

```
<input id="vendors" type="text" value="@Model.InvoiceMaster.VendorId" class="form-control" />
```

I have tried  this but it errors out with Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
<input id="vendors" type="text" value="@Model.InvoiceMaster.Vendors.Name" class="form-control" />
```

Here is my class structure

```
    public int VendorId { get; set; }

    public Vendors Vendors { get; set; }
```

Here is my controller

```
        var invoiceDetails = _context.InvoiceDetails.ToList();
        var invoiceMaster= _context.InvoiceMaster.ToList();
        var vendors = _context.Vendors.ToList();

        var viewModel = new InvoiceMasterViewModel
        {
            InvoiceMaster = invoiceMaster,
            InvoiceDetails = invoiceDetails,
            Vendors = vendors

        };
```

Comment: You don't show your Vendor model but is there a chance that one of your Vendor's Name properties is "null" in your database or wherever you are retrieving them from?

Comment: You populated `Vendors` obj only in `InvoiceMasterViewModel` not in `InvoiceMaster`. It would only be accessible by `@Model.InvoiceMasterViewModel.Vendors.Name`. You should consider creating a fk relation here.

Comment: I convert it to the viewModel in the View. Ex: @model ViewModels.InvoiceMasterViewModel